# How to pass Array of Objects from Angular Front-end to C# Back-end

Tags: c#, arrays, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, controller

I've generated an array of objects in Angular and I want it to send it to the C# controller. How can I do this?

This is the code for generating the array of objects.

```
var addObjectToArray = function (id, price, quantity, tax) {
  $scope.element = {
    prodId: id,
    patientId: $state.params.patientId,
    clinicId: $cookies.get("clinicId"),
    user: authService.authentication.userName,
    price: price,
    quantity: quantity,
    tax: tax,
    subtotal: price * quantity,
    total: price * quantity + tax
  };
  $scope.productsArray.push({ product: $scope.element });
}
```

This is the C# controller. How can I pass the array of objects as the second parameter in the C# Controller?

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("... the route ...")]
[ResponseType(typeof(int))]
public IHttpActionResult InsertNewProductTotal(int clinicId) // << HOW CAN I GET THE ARRAY OF OBJECTS HERE ??? >>
{
    var newAttorney = _productSaleLogic.InsertNewProductTotal(clinicId, productsList);
    return Created(Request.RequestUri.ToString(), newAttorney);
}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Create a ViewModel (class) which will contain a Id property and collection (of type IEnumerable) property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `Route` contains the clinicId, in a way similar to this:

```
[Route("{clinicId:int}")]
```

Then you need to add a parameter to your controller action using the correct type:

```
public IHttpActionResult InsertNewProductTotal(int clinicId, [HttpPost] Product[] productsList)
{
    var newAttorney = _productSaleLogic.InsertNewProductTotal(clinicId, productsList);
    return Created(Request.RequestUri.ToString(), newAttorney);
}
```

where `Product` is a class that represents your javascript object:

```
public class Product {
    public int prodId {get; set;}
    public int patientId {get; set;}
    //etc.
}
```

In your angular Controller you have to use the `$http` service to post the array of objects to your api endpoint:

```
$http.post("http://myapihost/myapiPath/" + clinicId, $scope.productsArray)
    .then(function (response) {
        //ok! do something
    }, function (error) {
        //handle error
    });
```

Of course, if you are not putting the `clinicId` parameter inside your `Route` attribute, then you should use the following URI for your `$http.post`: `"http://myapihost/myapiPath?clinicId=" + clinicId`.

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/products/{clinicId}")]

public IHttpActionResult InsertNewProductTotal(int clinicId,[FromBody]Product[]) // << HOW CAN I GET THE ARRAY OF OBJECTS HERE ??? >>
{
    var newAttorney = _productSaleLogic.InsertNewProductTotal(clinicId, productsList);
    return Created(Request.RequestUri.ToString(), newAttorney);
}
```

then From angular you can do something like this

```
$http.post("http://api/products/" + clinicId, $scope.productsArray)
    .then(function (response) {
        //ok! do something
    }, function (error) {
        //handle error
    })
```